# Weird error for use of keyCode should be working

Tags: javascript, html

I'm getting an error with my `event.keyCode` saying that

> Cannot read property 'keyCode'

I want the code to when I press "I" to load the screen that I have drawn onto my canvas

```
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");

document.addEventListener('keydown', loadScreen);

canvas.width=640;

canvas.height=640;

var draw = canvas.getContext("2d");


loadScreen();



function loadScreen(event) {
var key = (event.keyCode);
if(key == 73)
{
InventoryScreen();
}
}


function InventoryScreen()
{
draw.fillStyle = "#D3D3D3";
draw.fillRect(50,50,100,80);
draw.fillRect(50,135,100,80);
draw.fillRect(50,220,100,80);
draw.fillRect(50,305,100,80);
draw.fillRect(50,390,100,80);
draw.fillRect(50,475,100,80);

draw.fillRect(495,50,100,80);
draw.fillRect(495,135,100,80);
draw.fillRect(495,220,100,80);
draw.fillRect(495,305,100,80);
draw.fillRect(495,390,100,80);
draw.fillRect(495,475,100,80);


draw.fillRect(155,50,335,505);

}
```

Comment: `keyCode` is deprecated, you should be using `key`

Comment: note: you call `loadScreen();` ... so at least that time `event` will be undefined

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is here:

```
loadScreen();
```

You are calling `loadScreen` without passing it an event.

You can fake it by doing this:

```
loadScreen({keyCode:73});
```

---

Note that when `loadScreen` is set to be called by an `Event` here:

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', loadScreen);
```

…every time a keyboard key is pressed down, an `event` object is passed as the first argument, and that `event` object contains a `keyCode` value that corresponds with the key pressed.

---

I was able to wrap your code in a test HTML document, and it produced some nice-looking gray rectangles:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test of Stackoverflow question 49583733</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
```

*your code here, adding `{keyCode:73}`*

```
}) ;

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```